# Find all $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $t_1L_1+t_2L_2=\vec{0}^{\,}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

### This is the problem.

---

[image]

---

### The solution is below.

How did they row reduce the matrix like that below? How did the $x_i$ variables become $1$s and $0$s? I'd like someone to further clarify the solution.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to have :

$$t_1L_1 + t_2L_2 = \vec{0}$$

By substituting in, this translates to the vector equation :

$$t_1(7x_1,x_2-5x_3) + t_2(x_1+6x_2+x_3,x_3)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases} 7t_1x_1 + t_2(x_1+6x_2 + x_3)=0 \\ (x_2-5x_3)t_1 + t_2x_3 = 0\end{cases}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases} (7t_1+t_2)x_1 + 6t_2x_2 + t_2x_3=0 \\ t_1x_2 + (t_2-5t_1)x_3 = 0 \end{cases}$$

In order for your system to be equal to $0$ for any pair of coordinates, you need the coefficients to be zero, hence :

$$\begin{cases} 7t_1 + t_2= 0, t_2 = 0 , t_2 = 0 \\ t_1 = 0 , t_2 - 5t_1 = 0 \end{cases}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$t_1=t_2 = 0$$

What the author is doing there is that he is converting the pair of equations to a matrix expression factoring out $t_1,t_2$ and applying row operations (alike Gauss' Elimination) to the matrix of the system that gets formed to elementary show that the $X,Y$ corresponding parts must be equal to $0$, since from the last matrix he derives $1\cdot X + 0 = 0$ and $0 + 1\cdot Y = 0$, which ultimately means that $t_1=t_2=0$ as proved above.

Comment: "In order for your system to be equal to 0 for any pair of coordinates, you need the coefficients to be zero, hence :" This is an unjustified assumption since the question is asking whether or not you need the coefficients to be zero, or if there is a non-zero solution. Hence you have to justify this statement as it essentially answers the question.

Comment: Try solving the system with respect to one unknown and substituting. In this case, you will have a random variable with values over the reals. The only way this random expression which will depend on a variable to be zero would be for the coefficients to be zero. I didn't elaborate that but you can easily figure it out, as you have a 2×2 system with 3 unknowns!

Comment: What's the explanation for the matrix reductions they did in the provided solution in my original post?

Comment: The system derived by the way I described or by the linearity of the solutions giving you the zero vector 8s reduced into a Gaussian form of elimination, as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: When I used your method and reduced it into a Gaussian form, I didn't have any "x"s in the matrix to start with since I was solving for (c1t1+c2t2+...) = 0, so I just put the coefficients c1, c2... into the matrix. How would using your method and then putting it into a matrix get "x" variables in the matrix? And how would we "eliminate" the "x" variables as shown in the solution I posted when there are only two rows and so many variables?

Comment: How did you have no variables? I can't rally understand your mistake of you don't include your attempt at the question form. Apply substitutions for the variables and you will yield an equation with an unrestricted variable which means the coefficient most be zero since the variable can also take non zero values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the notation was confusing...

t1 * $\mathbf{L1}$ + t2 * $\mathbf{L2}$ = $\vec{0}$

or

$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{L1} & \mathbf{L2}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} t1 \\ t2 \end{pmatrix}$ = $\vec{0}$

or

$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}\mathbf{L1} & \mathbf{L2} & \vec{0} \end{array}\right)$

Then to row reduce this matrix ...

Add $-((x_2-5x_3)/7x_1)*row1$ to $row2$:

$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}\begin{matrix} 7x_1 \\ 0  \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} x_1 + 6x_2 + x_3 \\ BLOB_1 \end{matrix} & \vec{0} \end{array}\right)$

Add $-((x_1+6x_2+x_3)/BLOB_1)*row2$ to $row1$:

$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}\begin{matrix} 7x_1 \\ 0  \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} 0 \\ BLOB_1 \end{matrix} & \vec{0} \end{array}\right)$

Then, normalize $row1$ and $row2$

$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} & \vec{0} \end{array}\right)$

Comment: No, I understand that. What I don't understand is how the $x_i$s disappear after that, and how that matrix was reduced.

Comment: Sorry for the delay...